# Constraint in Choco

Tags: java, constraint-programming, choco

I've found a Choco [solver](https://sourceforge.net/projects/choco/) as constraint programming software working with Java. I would like to learn it more. I have done some basic example. But now I would like to try something more complex (Pritsker project scheduling alg) and I need your help. In order to progress I have to understand how to put constraints on rows of matrix variable. Exactly I need to keep a sum of rows equal 1 (task starts only once). I have tried it but unsuccessfuly. Could you help? I do use Choco 2.1.5 My matrix is as follows:

```
int n = 10; // projects
int m = 12; // time horizon in months
IntegerVariable[][] x = new IntegerVariable[n][m];
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++){
        x[i][j] = Choco.makeIntVar("x_" + i +"_" + j, 0, 1, Options.V_ENUM);
        model.addVariable(x[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define variables as `rows` and `columns` first.

Than, you may use [this](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~pat/cpM/jchoco/jchoco2.1.0/manuals/choco.pdf) documentation to proceed. Something like this might be helpful:

```
IntegerVariable[][] rows;
int n; //number of rows
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
   model.addConstraint(eq(sum(rows[i], 1));
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I will redo it and come back. I was trying to sum using 2 indexes and ended up with the constraint for each cell... My second approach was to use scalar method but it didnt work also.

Comment: Ok, It solved my problem. I got another one issue to be solved in order to implement a scheduling alg. What if I would like to have some coefficients for each x[i][j] variable, to be used in a formulation of the goal? When I try something like this:
`for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
for (j = 0; j < m; j++){
z[i][j] = Choco.mult(j, x[j][i]); // here I've got error
}
}`
where z is just a temporal variable:
`IntegerVariable[][] z = new IntegerVariable[n][m];`
I've got the following error:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from IntegerExpressionVariable to IntegerVariable.
Any idea how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: `Choco.mult(j, x[j][i])` returns and `IntegerExpressionVariable`. An `IntegerVariable` is a decision variable, which means an integer to be picked among a domain. But `IntegerExpressionVariable` is a constant variable. So, you need to define `z` as an `IntegerExpressionVariable`

Comment: I got the point. For now I did something simple. Just for my 5 projects and horizon of 12 months:
`int[] horizon = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
IntegerVariable goal= Choco.makeIntVar("goal", 1, 1000000, Options.V_BOUND);
model.addConstraint(Choco.eq(Choco.sum(
Choco.scalar(x[0], horizon), 
Choco.scalar(x[1], horizon),
Choco.scalar(x[2], horizon),
Choco.scalar(x[3], horizon),
Choco.scalar(x[4], horizon)), goal));
Solver solver = new CPSolver();
solver.read(model);
solver.minimize(solver.getVar(goal), false);`
I'm sure that the above constraint should be in one line. But how?

Comment: @JAW try this: `eq(plus(sum(x),horizon));`

Comment: It requires to create method: `sum(IntegerVariable[][])`

Answer (score 0):

To add constraint over the rows, you should transpose the matrix and apply the constraint over the lines :

```
transposed = ArrayUtils.transpose(x);
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
    model.sum(transposed[i], "=", 1);
}
```